# Is it possible to set different colors for different lines in a javafx textField/Area?

Tags: java, colors, javafx, textarea, textfield

I know that you can set a color of a whole textArea/Field by setting the style of the node to be `-fx-text-fill: red;` but is there a way to set the color of one single line instead of all of the lines while still keeping the textArea/Field editable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaFX's `TextField`/`TextArea` does not support that. You can use [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) for the job:

```
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea;

InlineCssTextArea area = new InlineCssTextArea();

// set style of line 4
area.setStyle(4, "-fx-fill: red;");
```

Answer (score 10):

With javaFX 8 (released March, 2016) it is possible to use TextFlow instead of TextArea or TextField. It allows different colors, fonts etc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer TextFlow, instead of RichTextFX.