# How to change color of single line inside textarea using javafx controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have textarea which show file data content. I have table view which contains line numbers and when double click on table view I can able to retrieve line number so I need to change the color of particular line number in textarea using JavaFx controller. How to do that? Please share your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code. 
With the TextArea UI-Control you can only add color to the whole containing text. 
For your purpose you should use [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) to style your text content individually.

See also: [Using JavaFX UI Controls - HTML Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm)

Comment: Is there any other way other than HTML Editor because i dont need paragraph styling and cut and other options .Just i need show text data by highlighting the perticular line from controller.

Comment: No, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075841/how-to-hide-the-controls-of-htmleditor), Java FX doesn't support such UI-Control apparently . But try one of [his](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23203211/3102124) answers .

Comment: i have got one link from stackoverflow regarding this https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX and stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114478/is-it-possible-to-set-different-colors-for-different-lines-in-a-javafx-textfield

Comment: @chethan When this solved your problem.. please mark this as an answer :) thanks.